Is there any specific terminology for this type of current in spintronics?
In spintronics, there are several types of currents:

Spin-polarized current: The two spins flow in the same direction with unequal contributions.
Perfectly spin-polarized current: Only one species of spins flows in one direction.
Pure spin current: The two spins flow in opposite directions with the same magnitude. The flow of charge becomes zero.

I have an additional type to share with you. The two spins flow in opposite directions with different magnitudes. Thus, the charge flow does not vanish. Is there specific terminology for this type? Which kind of material hosts this type?
